# Widget onUpdate is not setting pendingIntent on button click after reboot

Tags: android, widget, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I'm creating a test widget that shows random number by clicking its button. everything is inside `onUpdate` of my `Provider` independently, including the `pendingIntent`. it works fine but after rebooting the phone `views.setOnClickPendingIntent` is not working although `RemoteViews` is recreated with no issue but the button becomes unresponsive.

```
public class TestWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    static HashMap<Integer, BroadcastReceiver> br = new HashMap<>();

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                final int appWidgetId) {
        context = context.getApplicationContext();
        final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.test_widget);

        BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, Math.random() + "");
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            }
        };
        br.put(appWidgetId, broadcastReceiver);//to unregister later

        Intent intent = new Intent("action");
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("action");

        context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_button, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            context.unregisterReceiver(br.get(appWidgetId));
        }
    }
}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.aeza.sta">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <receiver android:name=".TestWidget" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/test_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".TestWidgetConfigureActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Dynamically registering your Receiver there for that broadcast is shaky, at best. I'm kinda surprised it worked at all. Anyhoo, an `AppWidgetProvider` is just a specialized `BroadcastReceiver`. If you want your `TestWidget` class to handle that click, just create an explicit `Intent` for `TestWidget`, and optionally set some unique action `String`. You can then override `onReceive()`, check if the delivered `Intent` has no action – or your unique action, whichever – and do your refresh if it does.

Comment: If not, then call `super.onReceive(context, intent);`, and `AppWidgetProvider` will then delegate the broadcast to the appropriate Widget method.  All Widget broadcasts will have non-null actions.

Comment: yes thank you, you were right, it seems registering my receiver Dynamically "that way" was all wrong and creating the widget inside Provider's own receiver is the standard way I suppose.

Comment: I would choose best answer if it was a there though

Comment: After rebooting, the best way to restore state is to use onEnabled. So you can set a new RemoteViews on onEnabled, and your widget will be responsive as before. And make countering of your clicks in OnReceive in your AppWidgetProvider, as someone said before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically registering `BroadcastReceiver`s in an `AppWidgetProvider` is a shaky solution, at best. `AppWidgetProvider` itself is a `BroadcastReceiver`, and instances of those statically registered in an app's manifest are meant to be rather short-lived.

However, since `AppWidgetProvider` is a `BroadcastReceiver`, we can take advantage of that, and simply target your `TestWidget` in the click `PendingIntent`s. We can also attach the Widget ID as an extra to the `Intent` here, so we update the correct one when the click fires. For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, TestWidget.class);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                                                         appWidgetId,
                                                         intent,
                                                         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_button, pendingIntent);
```

Note that we've also used the `appWidgetId` for the `PendingIntent`'s `requestCode`. It's important that a distinct `PendingIntent` is used for each Widget instance, lest the wrong Widget instance be updated with the wrong extras. Using the already-unique Widget ID allows us to do that easily.

We then override `TestWidget`'s `onReceive()` method, and check the `Intent`'s action to determine if this is our click broadcast, or a normal Widget event broadcast from the system. In the example above, we didn't set an action, so we'll simply check for null here. However, you certainly could specify an action `String`, and it may be preferable to do so in some cases; e.g., if you have multiple `Button`s in your Widget, and need to distinguish their click broadcasts.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction() == null) {
        int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
        if (appWidgetId != -1) {
            updateWidgetText(context, appWidgetId, Math.random() + "");
        }
    }
    else {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

In the above, you can see that we pass the broadcast to the `super` method if we've found that it's not ours. `AppWidgetProvider`'s `onReceive()` will then examine the `Intent`, and delegate to the appropriate event method, per usual.

Apart from being a stable solution, this approach has another upshot, in that a separate `BroadcastReceiver` instance does not need to be created, registered, and then unregistered for each Widget instance. Though we've added an `onReceive()` method, we can remove all of the dynamic `BroadcastReceiver` code, so our `TestWidget` class is still pretty short and simple.

```
public class TestWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() == null) {
            int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
            if (appWidgetId != -1) {
                updateWidgetText(context, appWidgetId, Math.random() + "");
            }
        }
        else {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
    }

    static void updateWidgetText(Context context, int appWidgetId, String newText) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.test_widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, newText);
        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                final int appWidgetId) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.test_widget);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TestWidget.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                                                                 appWidgetId,
                                                                 intent,
                                                                 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_button, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems you already answered my next problem thank you, I was struggling with adding multiple buttons to do different things but all of them would behave as if the last button is triggered so I was starting to fiddle with the intent's action name again till I figured from you answer having unique pendingIntent's code is the solution, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

this is the complete result of the above test project if anyone has similar problem.
multiple buttons are added dynamically in configuration page and each has a user defined behavior.
https://github.com/Alireza-Jamali/daily-task-checker