# Managing click button from App Widget

Tags: android, android-studio, widget, android-widget

I am working on a widget only application to play a alarm sound on click of the widget. I just want to start playing the sound on click of the widget and stop playing if clicked again. I am facing two issues and finding it difficult to solve this. 
1) The alarm start to sound at the time i drag and drop the widget to home screen.
2) I cannot make the sound stop on click of the widget.

help will be appreciated...
these are my codes

androidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name=".BuzzerWidget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/buzzer_widget_info" />
    </receiver>
</application>
```

appwidget_Provider.xml

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/buzzer_widget"
android:initialLayout="@layout/buzzer_widget"
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:minWidth="40dp"
android:previewImage="@drawable/buzzer_image"
android:updatePeriodMillis="10000"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen"></appwidget-provider>
```

widget layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#09C"
android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/buzzer_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/buzzerButton"
        android:src="@drawable/buzzer_image"/>  
</LinearLayout>
```

widget java file

```
public class BuzzerWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
MediaPlayer mplayer;
private static boolean isPlaying = false;

void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {
    Log.d("BUZZER", "on updateAppWidget");
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.buzzer_widget);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BuzzerWidget.class);
    intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    int[] idArray = new int[]{appWidgetId};
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, idArray);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buzzerButton, pendingIntent);
    mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.buzzer_alarm);

    if (isPlaying) {
        isPlaying = false;

        Log.d("BUZZER", "playing");
        if(mplayer != null) {
            mplayer.release();
            mplayer = null;
        }

    } else {
        isPlaying = true;

        Log.d("BUZZER", "not playing");

        if (!mplayer.isPlaying()){
            mplayer.start();
        }

    }

    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        Log.d("BUZZER", "on update");
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    intent.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
}
```

}

Comment: 1) If you don't have a configuration `Activity` for the Widget, it's going to get an `APPWIDGET_UPDATE` broadcast right after you place it. Furthermore, it's going to get that same broadcast every time the system wants it to update, so your current design is probably not what you want. Use a custom action for your `Intent` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49043273 2) Each time you get a broadcast, the system creates a new instance of the Receiver, and therefore a new `MediaPlayer`. Move the `MediaPlayer` stuff into a `Service`, where you can maintain the same instance until you stop it.

Comment: @ Mike M. How can i move the mediaplayer to a service and make it start and stop on click